# Hue Impersonation without a wildcard

Tags: hue

I'm trying to resolve a

```
User: hue is not allowed to impersonate hue
```

Error in my Bigtop Hadoop setup... but, I'm trying to avoid wildcarding the hadoop.proxyuser.hue.groups setting like all the examples show.

Is it possible to have Hue run without having to open up all the groups?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed to add a hue user to the Namenode